# Number of ways of cutting a stick such that the longest portion is of length n

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, integer-partitions

We are given a stick of length $L$ (say). We make cuts such that the **longest** piece is of length $n$ (say) at most.
What are the **minimum** number of pieces we will get and in how many ways this can be done? e.g

We have a stick of length 7. We want the longest piece of the stick to be of length 3 at most.

Soln. :The minimum number of pieces is 3 and there are 6 ways to make 2 cuts :

1. positions: 1 4 (length of portions will be 1(0-1), 3(1-4), 3(4-7))
2. positions: 3 4 (length of portions will be 3,1,3)
3. positions: 3 6 (length of portions will be 3,3,1)
4. positions: 2 4 (length of portions will be 2,2,3)
5. positions: 2 5 (length of portions will be 2,3,2)
6. positions: 3 5 (length of portions will be 3,2,3)

How can this be solved for large values of $L$ and $n$?

Comment: It's a little strange to speak of "cutting a stick" when (it seems) you are restricting to integer lengths, no?

Comment: The [currently accepted answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2268630/26369) is incorrect at the time of this comment. [Med](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/261160/med) might yet be able to fix it, though.

Answer (score 1):

The basic Idea is : Given example L=17, n=4. 
One such way to distribute this is : 
 
4|4|4|4|1

Now, we can move some values from the first 4 slots to the last slot '1'. 
 We can add a max value of 3 to the last slot since [1+3=n] and we cannot have a piece with >n length.

So, by using multinomial theorem, we need to find solutions to: 
x1+x2+x3+x4 <= 3 
which is the same as x1+x2+x3+x4+x5=3.

We know that the formula for non-negative solutions of x1+x2+x3....+xm=p is: (p+m-1)C(m-1) 
Reference : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)

Its easy to see that m = (ceil(L/n)) and p = (n - L%n).

Special case : When L%n=0, then there is only 1 way to cut and number of pieces = L/n.

Edit :

Related Problem for Reference : https://www.codechef.com/MAY17/problems/SANDWICH

Answer (score 0):

Try L=8, n=2; that means k=4 and applying the above formula, its 5, which i think is incorrect. I cant be making 4 cuts in such a way that i get only 4 pieces of size 2 or less.

the correct answer is one (as i can do this in only one way)

Comment: This is the only case. If L mod n=0, then the answer will be 1. In the rest of the cases, it was the correct formula I guess.

Answer (score -1):

The minimum number of pieces would be $k=\lceil \frac{L}{n} \rceil$. Because you want to put as much as you can in each piece to minimise the number of pieces. Therefore, you want to have each piece to have the length $n$. There can be $\lfloor \frac{L}{n} \rfloor$ piece of length $n$, plus one piece of a length less than $n$.

Having the number of pieces $k$, you may use stars and bars method to deal with the rest. First you compute the number of possible positions, while having no upper limit for any of the pieces. So, the problem is as below

$$x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_k=L-k$$

and the solution is

$$\binom{L-1}{k-1}$$

Then, you need to take some possibilities, that have lengths greater than $n$, out. To do so, you take one of $x_i$ at a time and choose its length to be $n$. There are $\binom{k}{1}=1$ ways to choose one. Then, for each $x_i$, solve the following problem.

$$x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_k=L-(k+n)$$

$$\binom{L-n-1}{k-1}$$

The final solution would be

$$\binom{L-1}{k-1}-k\binom{L-n-1}{k-1}$$

Comment: Shouldn't $ k = \lceil L / n \rceil$?

Comment: @PaulAljabar, I have added a $1$ to it

Comment: @PaulAljabar: You're correct. If you have a stick of length $6$ and cut it into pieces with length $2$ at most, then the minimum is $3$, not $4$ as this answer would suggest.

Comment: You were right. I edited the answer. How could I neglect?

Comment: @Med, your answer is off by $1$ for cases where $L=n$. A much bigger problem is that it's off by unpredictable amounts when $n\ll L$. As [Ramanan](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/445660/ramanan) attempted to point out in [his answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2277580/26369), the first case of this is where $L=8$ and $n=2$. In that case, the correct answer is $1$ (as $2,2,2,2$ is the only solution), but your formula yields $-5$. The number of wrong answer cases for a given $L$ just grows as $L$ increases. I don't think this will be trivial to fix.

Comment: @Mark S., I usually try to demonstrate a way of thinking and do not concern myself with the detail and, obviously, I make mistakes every now and then. I do not really get it when a hint of two words gets up-voted, while a way of thinking is always criticised. It is not the first time anyway, so do what ever you want. Needless to say that I know in combinatorics even a unit of error matters.

Comment: @Med, the psychology of a short hint being read over a long presentation of how to approach something bothers me too.

Comment: @Med, This problem is hard, and I simply didn't want someone to stumble upon it and think this answer was correct. I will happily upvote if it is edited to make it clear that it doesn't contain the correct answer, as the stars and bars idea is related (if insufficient). I haven't been able to solve the problem in a satisfying way myself, but if you are able to find a complete solution, I'd happily offer a bounty. I don't know if you were concerned about this, but I didn't bother downvoting the other answer because I flagged it as not an answer and thought it would be deleted by now.

Comment: @MarkS., you are right. I did not notice my mistake. It seems I cannot delete it.